# How to register api controller from a library with configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What I have done is created a small API in a class library. This API would be used by other sites.  Think of it as a standard endpoint that all of our websites will contain.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CustomController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

The above is in a class library.  Now what i would like to do is be able to add this to the projects in a simple manner.

```
app.UseCustomAPI("/api/crap");
```

I am not exactly sure how i should handle routing to the api controllers in the library.  I created a  CustomAPIMiddleware which is able to catch that i called "/api/crap" however i am not sure how i should forward the request over to CustomController in the library

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        PathString matched;
        PathString remaining;
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(_options.PathMatch, out matched, out remaining))
        {
            PathString path = context.Request.Path;
            PathString pathBase = context.Request.PathBase;
            context.Request.PathBase = pathBase.Add(matched);
            context.Request.Path = remaining;
            try
            {
                await this._options.Branch(context);
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Request.PathBase = pathBase;
                context.Request.Path = path;
            }
            path = new PathString();
            pathBase = new PathString();
        }
        else
            await this._next(context);
    }
```

After having done that i am starting to think i may have approached this in the wrong manner and should actually be trying to add it directly to the routing tables somehow.   That being said i would like it if they could customize the endpoint that the custom controller reads from.

**Update**

The following does work.   [Loading and registering API Controllers From Class Library in ASP.NET core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40491893/1841839)

```
services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddApplicationPart(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("WebAPI")));
```

However i am really looking for a middlewere type solution so that users can simply add it and i can configure the default settings or they can change some of the settings.   The above example would not allow for altering the settings.

```
 app.UseCustomAPI("/api/crap");
```

**Update from comment without Assembly**

If i dont add the  `.AddApplicationPart(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("WebAPI")));`

> This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: 
>   https://localhost:44368/api/Custom

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/40491893/993547

Comment: Close but its a bit cumbersome and doesn't allow for configuration.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-2.2#introducing-application-parts): "By default MVC will search the dependency tree and find controllers (even in other assemblies).". I realise it's secondary to the main question now, but you shouldn't need to use an application-part for this if the hosting project references the `WebAPI` assembly shown.

Comment: @KirkLarkin what i want to do is allow the users to change the endpoint.  So that they are not stuck with api/custom and could change it to api/crap if they like

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To customise the routing for a controller at runtime, you can use an [Application Model Convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2#conventions). This can be achieved with a custom implementation of [`IControllerModelConvention`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.icontrollermodelconvention):

```
public class CustomControllerConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    private readonly string newEndpoint;

    public CustomControllerConvention(string newEndpoint)
    {
        this.newEndpoint = newEndpoint;
    }

    public void Apply(ControllerModel controllerModel)
    {
        if (controllerModel.ControllerType.AsType() != typeof(CustomController))
            return;

        foreach (var selectorModel in controllerModel.Selectors)
            selectorModel.AttributeRouteModel.Template = newEndpoint;
    }
}
```

This example just replaces the existing template (`api/[controller]`) with whatever is provided in the `CustomControllerConvention` constructor. The next step is to register this new convention, which can be done via the call to `AddMvc`. Here's an example of how that works:

```
services.AddMvc(o =>
{
    o.Conventions.Add(new CustomControllerConvention("api/whatever"));
});
```

That's all that's needed to make things work here, but as you're offering this up from another assembly, I'd suggest an extension method based approach. Here's an example of that:

```
public static class MvcBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IMvcBuilder SetCustomControllerRoute(
        this IMvcBuilder mvcBuilder, string newEndpoint)
    {
        return mvcBuilder.AddMvcOptions(o =>
        {
            o.Conventions.Add(new CustomControllerConvention(newEndpoint));
        });
    }
}
```

Here's how that would be called:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCustomControllerRoute("api/whatever");
```

This whole approach means that without a call to `SetCustomControllerRoute`, `api/Custom` will still be used as a default.