# Asp.net core - Web Api on Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, class-library

I am trying to make n-tier application where web api is kept on a different class library. I made a `TestController` controller class in a different class library and my code goes like this

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PkrUni.SMS.Api
{
    [ApiController]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "Chris", "Hadfield" };
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is how can I access this web api on my main project. I had already added a reference to that class library on main project but it doesn't working. My api is not working. **404 Page Not Found** error shows up while trying to access the api.
This is my project structure.

[image]

What am I doing wrong please help me.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617994/how-to-use-a-controller-in-another-assembly-in-asp-net-core-mvc-2-0). The controllers are referenced, but the app doesn't know to look for controllers in any assembly but its own.

Comment: Why did you put the controllers in a separate project anyways? That's not really required for an N-Tier app.

Comment: @mason Api controller are only on different project but mvc controller are in main project. Is it bad practice to have api controller in different class

Comment: It's not necessarily bad. But what advantage does it give you? I can't think of any. And if it's making it harder to build/run your app....I think you should think of the positives and negatives of your approach and decide whether it's worth it.

Comment: @mason Can you tell me how to call an web api without exposing it on network tab of browser.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @mason Coz I don't wanna show how I consume my api to others

Comment: You don't want others to be able to hit your Web API? Who is the intended audience for it? Who should be to talk to it?

Comment: @mason I just want to know it. Can this be possible

Comment: I don't even know what you're asking so I can't tell you whether it's possible or not. Please answer my question: who should be able to talk to your Web API? What code will be responsible for calling your Web API?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192588/discussion-between-chris-hadfield-and-mason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` package in the razor class library.
And in startup.cs use:

```
services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("PkrUni.SMS.Area.Api")));
```

Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491893/loading-and-registering-api-controllers-from-class-library-in-asp-net-core).

I test your scenario by creating a asp.net core2.2 MVC project and razor class library  without any problem. Below is my structure:

[image]