# Asp.Net Core produces 404 when API is separated into multiple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to break out reusable code for the APIs that I have to create, but there is one issue that has had me stumped for a few days now.  When all of the code resides in a single project, `WebAPI` and the common code exists within a folder called `Core`, everything works.

Now, if I take the code within `Core` and put it in its own project `WebAPI.Core`, the API starts, Swagger loads, but every request produces 404. I have narrowed down the problem, and it only occurs when `Startup` and `Program` are in different projects.  Is that the intended behavior, or did I do something wrong?

Here is the `Startup` which is located in the `WebAPI.Core` project:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
        {
            options.UseApiBehavior = false;
            options.ReportApiVersions = true;
            options.ApiVersionReader = new HeaderApiVersionReader("api-version");
            options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
        });
        services.AddMvc(options => { options.EnableEndpointRouting = false; });
        services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
        {
            options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
            options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
        });

        services
            .AddControllers(options => options.Filters.Add(new ErrorFilter()))
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        const string swagger = "Swagger";


        app.UseMvc(routes => routes.MapRoute("default", "/{controller}/{action}/{*id}", new {id = string.Empty}));
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(builder => builder.MapControllers());

        var directory = Combine(Api.CurrentDirectory, swagger);

        if (Exists(directory))
        {
            Delete(directory, true);
        }

        CreateDirectory(directory);

        app.UseDefaultFiles().UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(directory),
            RequestPath = $"/{swagger}"
        });

        Api.Assembly.CreateDocuments(AppSettings["Title"], AppSettings["Description"], AppSettings["Name"], AppSettings["Email"], directory);

        app.UseSwaggerUI(setupAction =>
        {
            setupAction.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;

            foreach (var file in GetFiles(directory))
            {
                var fileName = GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                setupAction.SwaggerEndpoint($"/{swagger}/{fileName}.json", fileName.Replace("-", " "));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is `Api`, the link between `Startup` and `Program`, also located in `WebAPI.Core`:

```
public static class Api
{
    public static void Run<TStartup>(this Assembly assembly, string[] args) where TStartup : Startup
    {
        Assembly = assembly;
        CurrentDirectory = GetDirectoryName(UnescapeDataString(new UriBuilder(assembly.CodeBase).Path));

        CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<TStartup>(); }).Build().Run();
    }

    public static Assembly Assembly { get; private set; }

    public static string CurrentDirectory { get; private set; }
}
```

And finally, here is `Program`, located in `WebAPI`:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetExecutingAssembly().Run<Startup>(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: really strange way of linking assemblies. you could try creating separate class library with controllers and just add assembly to your main application, with one line of code. please see accepted answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491893/loading-and-registering-api-controllers-from-class-library-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo adding this `services.AddMvc(options => { options.EnableEndpointRouting = false; }).AddApplicationPart(Api.Assembly);` fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: glad it helped, you might want to post solution yourself to avoid people coming in future (looking for points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out in one of the comments, I was missing a link to the API assembly.

from:

```
 services.AddMvc(options => { options.EnableEndpointRouting = false; });
```

to:

```
services.AddMvc(options => { options.EnableEndpointRouting = false; }).AddApplicationPart(Api.Assembly);
```

and here is some extra information on [AddApplicationPart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-3.1).