# Storing IServiceProvider in a globally accessible static field to supply class libraries with dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have tried to look for simple solutions for dependency injection into class libraries.

I have tried to solve this with a simple solution and it seems to work fine.

This is what I did.

1. Create a global static class (in a separate class library):

```cs
namespace CompositionRoot
{    
    public static class Dependencies
    {
        public static IServiceProvider? ServiceProvider = null;   
    }
}
```

2. Create a service and add it to IServiceCollection (from Main).

```cs
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
IScriptRepository scriptRepository = new ScriptRepository(
    sensorDataConnectionString, "scripts", ControllerName, _logger);
services.AddSingleton(scriptRepository);
```

3. Create a IServiceProvider and add it to CompositionRoot (from Main):

```cs
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
CompositionRoot.Dependencies.ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
```

4. "Inject" the service object (in another class library)

```cs
private readonly IScriptRepository _scriptRepository;

public BuildingController()
{
    _scriptRepository =
        CompositionRoot.Dependencies.ServiceProvider!
            .GetService<IScriptRepository>()!;
}
```

I keep reading that this might be an "anti-pattern", but I'm not sure exactly why.

What are the potential issues with this approach?

Comment: Ideally, your library would have no idea which dependency injection library is being used. Your classes should simply depend on the things it needs, and they get injected by whatever mechanism the consumer wants to use. On the other hand, sometimes you need to macro-ize that registration. You can choose to depend directly on [`M.E.DI.Abstractions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions), and provide an extension method on `IServiceCollection` for that registration, or provide separate class libraries for each DI library you want to support...

Comment: ...and keep those separate from the main library, each with its own extension method specific to that DI library. What you've shown is the "service locator" anti-pattern because it depends on a specific way of getting dependencies, and that defeats the purpose.

Comment: As for what you *should* do, well, you have a few options (including what I said in my first comment above), but that's up to you to decide.

Answer (score 2):

Making the `IServiceProvider` accessible globally using a static field, as you do in your first code example, is an implementation of the Service Locator anti-pattern. This is generally discouraged, and the reasoning for this is explained in [this article](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/).

On top of the arguments given in that article, with MS.DI the problem becomes extraordinary clear, because resolving from the root service provider leads to all kinds of nasty bugs, such as [Captive Dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) and memory leaks, especially in applications that are request based. In other words, for applications where you (or the framework on your behalf) creates `IServiceScope` scopes. Generally, with MS.DI, services should be resolved from a scope - not the root container, but a static `ServiceProvider` field does not easily allow code to resolve from the proper 'scoped' service provider.

From perspective of applying Dependency Injection patterns and practices, registering the library's component inside the startup path of your application—your Main—is the sensible thing to do. This Main *is* your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). A Composition Root is the *centralized* location in the application were all dependencies are registered and all object graphs are composed. You don't want to scatter this logic throughout the application and you don't want to let libraries or projects themselves be in control over this registration and composition. Again, the Composition Root is the place to be.

Note that in this context, 'centralized' doesn't mean 'accessible by all', but rather 'grouped together'. As the Composition Root should live in the startup project of your application, it should not be accessed by any code that lives outside the Composition Root. The code inside the Composition Root takes a dependency on *everything* in the application, while everything that lives *outside* out the Composition Root (which would be 99% of your application) is oblivious to the existence of the Composition Root.

**IMPORTANT:** although you are using the term `CompositionRoot` in your example, that example shows the opposite of a the Composition Root pattern. In your example, the `Dependencies` class is shared—accessible to all—and, as I pointed out above, serves as a Service Locator.

If you want a deeper understanding of DI and its patterns such as the Composition Root, and its anti-patterns such as Service Locator, start by going through [this article](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-writing-maintainable-loosely-coupled-code/), the links at the bottom of that article. That article and two of the other references are excerpts from my book [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl) which, obviously, contains much more information than can be presented in articles only, let alone a StackOverflow answer. A freely available first chapter of this book is available [here](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1).

**UPDATE:**

To conclude, you should solely apply Constructor Injection, even for classes in the other projects/libraries of your solution and you should register those classes inside the Main/Composition Root of your startup project. In your case, this would look like this:

```
// Class in library project
public class BuildingController
{
    private readonly IScriptRepository _scriptRepository;

    // Apply Constructor Injection here
    public BuildingController(IScriptRepository scriptRepository)
    {
        _scriptRepository = scriptRepository
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}

// Inside the Composition Root of your startup project
services.AddTransient<BuildingController>();
```

Comment: Thanks! "A Service Locator may seem innocuous, but it can lead to all sorts of nasty runtime errors. How do you avoid those problems? The default approach should be to apply Constructor Injection, unless another DI pattern provides a better fit." I don't understand how constructor injection can be used in a class library.

Comment: @OlavT: See my update. I demonstrate how to apply Ctor Injection in your class library and how to add classes inside the Composition Root. If there are any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Btw, is your `BuildingController` an MVC controller that you want to use to handle web requests? And might it be that the actual problem you are facing is that your `BuildingController` doesn't get called when you call `http://localhost/api/building`? Make sure to add your library as application part, e.g. `services.AddMvc().services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(...)`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491893/loading-and-registering-api-controllers-from-class-library-in-asp-net-core).

Comment: No, BuildingController is not a part of a web project. Main is a console application running in a Docker container.